# 2 certificates on a node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, ssl

I have a NodeJS server running which is sucessfully acessed by 2 domains though HTTP.

Now those 2 sites have different SSL certificates.

What I want now, is to allow those 2 sites to connect to the node server via HTTPS.

I have sucessfully added one of the certificates... How should I procede to add the other one, or in other words, add 2 certificates to the same node server?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("keys/cer1.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("certs/cer2.crt"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("ca/ca.crt")
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  ...
}).listen(8000);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chicken and egg problem here: the server needs to decrypt the request to know which certificate to use - to decrypt the request ;)

There is [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which is designed to solve this - but I am not sure how that is implemented in node. Without this, you need to have a one to one mapping of port to certificate (this is the same issue every web server faces - hopefully SNI support will become the norm one day).

Comment: I was hoping for that to be the case... Thanks Michael